# Unable to login to MySQL command line unless logged in as root to unix

Tags: mysql, database, unix, database-administration

My Issues is that when I am logged in as a normal user on unix server and then try to login as `MySQL` root. It throws below error but when I am logged in as root to `unix` server and then try to connect to `MySQL` command line it allows me. I don't understand why is this happening. and how to resolve it. I want connect to `MySQL` command line with any normal `unix` user not root always.

```
-sh-4.2$ mysql -u root -pPASSWORD 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)

-sh-4.2$ su Password: 
[root@hostname]# mysql -u root -pPASSWORD 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g. Your MySQL
connection id is 78203 Server version: 5.5.52-log MySQL Community
Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights
reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input
statement.

mysql>
```

researched this across the internet but couldn't find any solution. I have also checked privileges to `MySQL` files and folder. they look fine to me.

it's just a connection command. Not much of code here.

it should connect to `MySQL` user irrespective of what `unix` user is logged in

Comment: Error 13 means permission denied. Check the permissions on `/var/lib/mysql` and `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`. The directory should have world read and execute, the socket needs to have world read and write.

Comment: If you don't know how to check this, add the output of `ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: Both the files have full permission and owner is mysql              srwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql 0 Sep  9 01:36 mysql.sock                            srwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql 0 Sep  9 01:36 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: I have 5 more servers, they all have full permission same as mentioned above and I am able to login to MySQL command like with any unix user login not necessary root only. Just in this one particular server it doesn't allow me.

Comment: Check to see if either account has a `.my.cnf` file that's changing how it connects to the server

Comment: @Barmar I have compared my.cnf in all these servers. They are identical. :(

Comment: Not the central `my.cnf` file for the servers, but `~/.my.cnf` for the accounts.

Comment: there is only one my.cnf in all respective servers.

Comment: There has to be something that's different, things don't just behave differently for no reason.

Comment: as far as my.cnf is concerned, files are identical. I strongly believe something is wrong. I found something interesting though, If I try to login MySQL -u test -pPASSWORD, it works fine for normal unix login. Still MySQL -u root -pPASSWORD failing.

Comment: That makes no sense. It doesn't check the username and password until after it connects to the MySQL server, and the error is about connecting to the server.

Comment: I agree that it's not usual behaviour but that's how it is. I still don't know what to do ?

Comment: This question should be in [dba.se], it has nothing to do with programming.